# Why is left:auto; right:auto not centering a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a image slider that needs to be centered horizontally. In order to make the `height` working I need to set the `position` of the slider to `absolute`. To center the slider I tried to set the left and right to auto like you see below.

```
#slider{
 position: absolute;
 width:80%;
 height:50%;
 left:auto;
 right:auto;
}
```

But this is not working.
I included a code snippet where you can see the rest of the code.

Can somebody also tell me why the `height` is not working without `position:absolute;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.active').css('display','inline')
});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
}
#slider{
    position:absolute;
 width:80%;
 height:50%;
 left:auto;
 right:auto;
}
#slider img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -5;
}
.active{
 z-index: 1;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <img src="http://icanbecreative.com/res/AbstractBg/green_abstract-wide.jpg" data-slide="1" class="active"/>
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05           /3d-abstract-hd-wallpaper.jpg" data-slide="2"/>
  <img src="http://freewallpaperspot.com/wallpapers/abstract-wallpaper-hd-3.jpg" data-slide="3"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: 1. margin:auto doesn't work with Position:absolute  ... 2. To set height with % values the parent needs a fixed height value too.

Comment: (for #2) what Danko said + and it works in your case because `body` has an "implicit" fixed height set by the window height.

Comment: @Danko I still don't understand why the height won't work without position absolute.

Comment: `#slider {
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
height: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translatex(-50%);
}` add this

Comment: _One question per question_, please. This height question is a _separate_ question.

Comment: Whitout absolute the parent of the element is the body who has no defined height ... When you set the position absolute is taken out of the flow and is no more the body since has static position now is the viewport who has fixed height ... @SergiuParaschiv your assumption is wrong

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes that works but I don't understand what you did because you add 50% and dan substract 50%

Comment: so that it becomes horizontal center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding this will align it horizontally center

```
#slider {
 position: absolute;
 width: 80%;
 height: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want position it to center with `position:absolute` simply add

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50% of container width
```

It's typical way of centering element, but remember that position: absolute will be calculated with respect to nearest parent with non-static position

Comment: So, maybe You don't need position: absolute. Are You sure it's necessary?

Answer (score -3):

You asked to position the slider `absolute`ly (i.e. with manual co-ordinates), then you complain that it's not automatically positioning itself? Hmm. :-)

Make it `position: relative`.